# create vector containing time matlab

Tags: matlab, time

I have a cell array containing the hours of a day.

```
hours = {'00:00:00', '01:00:00', '02:00:00', '03:00:00', '04:00:00', '05:00:00', '06:00:00', '07:00:00', '08:00:00', '09:00:00', '10:00:00', '11:00:00', '12:00:00',...
    '13:00:00', '14:00:00', '15:00:00', '16:00:00', '17:00:00', '18:00:00', '19:00:00', '20:00:00', '21:00:00', '22:00:00', '23:00:00'};
```

I created it manually :( ... now I would like to create another one with an interval of 15 minutes...do you have any tip to do it automatically?

```
hours_15 = {'00:00:00', '00:15:00','00:30:00',...,'23:45:00'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can achieve this by using datenum:

```
dt = datenum('00:15:00','HH:MM:ss') - datenum('00:00:00','HH:MM:ss'); % or: dt = 1/(24*4)
time_begin = datenum('00:00:00','HH:MM:ss');
time_end = datenum('23:45:00','HH:MM:ss');
hours_15 = cellstr(datestr(time_begin:dt:time_end,'HH:MM:ss'));
```

Answer (score 0):

A really simple by not so elegant solution:

```
hours = 0:23;
quarters = [0,15,30,45];
counter = 0;
% Pre-allocate space
C = cell(96,1)
for ii=1:24
    for jj=1:4
        counter=counter+1;
            C{counter} = sprintf('%02d:%02d:00',hours(ii),quarters(jj));
    end
end
```

It should be noted that this is taking a quarter of the time of the solution of Nras solution.